# ModelState.IsValid is false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an auto scaffold view

```
<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Event</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

And the controller is

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(EventCreateViewModel eventVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // Always false
        {
            var @event = new Event
            {
                EventName = eventVM.EventName,
                ......
                CreateTime = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
            };
            AddOrUpdateCategories(@event, eventVM.Categories);
            db.Events.Add(@event);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(eventVM);
    }
```

It doesn't save the data. And the `ModelState.IsValid` is always false. There is no message show in the html page `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`. How to get the reason of the failure?

Comment: Your markup example doesn't show any input fields.

Comment: pleqase put full code of your view here

Comment: can you change your question to show the entire cshtml page

Comment: The view is totally auto generated by visual studio. I will add more code when I have access to the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see all validation errors in validation summary, you should use it with false flag:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` means that all model property errors are suppressed from the summary. In order to see those errors, you have to add the individual validation messages:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YourModelProperty)
```

Comment: It shows error if I omit the required fields. Otherwise I cannot click the create button.

Comment: This is how it shoul work right. It should not allow you to create without entering required fields

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoint to the line with "if (ModelState.IsValid)"
Look into ModelState... there are 2 arrays - I think "Keys" and "Values". In Values array you can find what is wrong (is set to false) and in Keys you will find source of problem (look at the same index).